# why my new table cannot be added to my database

Tags: django-models, database-migration

I decide to add new Model called `Project` to my project:
When I run `python manage.py migrate`, it shows me the below error:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    statut_juridique=[
        ('per', 'personne physique' ),
        ('sarl', 'SARL'),
        ('sual', 'SUARL'),
        ('anony', 'SA'),
    ]
    type_du_projet = [
        ('ind', 'industrie'),
        ('agr', 'agronome'),
        ('ser', 'service'),
        ('art', 'artisanat'),
        ('com', 'commerce'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    produit = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True),
            size=8,
                    ),
        size=8,
    )
    stat_jur = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=statut_juridique)
    type_projet = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=type_du_projet)
    Nomination = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='projet', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth,
> businesplan, contenttypes, sessions Running migrations:   Applying
> contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/abdallah/projectdjango/oasis/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 87, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql) psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "django_content_type" already exists

And also I can't see the new table in my Database, Can you help me please!

Comment: You are probably using an old database that already has some tables set-up from a previous installation. Try using a different database, or reset your existing database to remove duplicate tables.

Answer (score -1):

You probably use a database that already has some tables with their migrations.
For this case you can Try using a new database, or reset your existing database to remove duplicate tables or sometimes you can troubleshot using `--fake-initial` as one of django-admin cmd option:

```
$ python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

From Django-Doc:

> Allows Django to skip an app’s initial migration if all database tables with the names of all models created by all CreateModel operations in that migration already exist. This option is intended for use when first running migrations against a database that preexisted the use of migrations. This option does not, however, check for matching database schema beyond matching table names and so is only safe to use if you are confident that your existing schema matches what is recorded in your initial migration.

Source: [**`django-admin#cmdoption-migrate-fake-initial`** <sup>[django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake-initial)